# Generally true that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} \int_{-\infty}^{a-y} f(x)\, \mathrm dx = f(a-y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, partial-derivative

Is it generally true that 
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} \int_{-\infty}^{a-y} f(x)\, \mathrm dx = f(a-y),$$
where $a$ and $y$ in the expression  are constants?

To give context to the question, I am reading about the function convolution of two independent random variables $X, Y$.

Comment: You are right considering chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is (for example) continuous, you are correct. To prove this, use the fundamental theorem of calculus in conjunction with the chain rule.

Let $$F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{z} f(x)  \ dx.$$

By the fundamental theorem, $F'(z)=f(z)$. In your problem, you want to evaluate the derivative of $F(a-y)$ with respect to $a$.

To use the chain rule, let's write $F(a-y)$ as a composition of two functions. Define $g(a)=a-y$. Then $F(a-y)=F(g(a))$. The derivative with respect to $a$, using the chain rule, is $F'(g(a))g'(a)$. We know $F'$ (it's $f$ -- see above), and we also know that $g'(a)=1$.

So $F'(g(a))g'(a)=F'(g(a))=f(a-y)$.

Comment: thanks...may I ask if you'd please go into the details of how to prove this? We may assume $f$ is continuous. In my case, $f$ is a probability distribution.

Comment: Wouldn't it too be necessary for $F(-\infty)$ to contain no $a$ term? If it does not, then $\frac{d}{da} F(-\infty)=0$, but if it does, it's not 0..

Comment: @FoF See my edit.

Comment: @hejseb What do you mean? The function $F$ is not defined at $-\infty$, really.

Comment: @Potato I see it. Forgive my calculus, it's really bad.  If it's not too much trouble, you please show the work of how we apply the chain rule to show this is equal to $f(a-y)$?

Comment: @FoF Please see my newest edit.

Comment: @Potato Yes, of course. Forgive my stupidity :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using the definition of derivative:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{d}{d a}\int_{\infty}^{a-y}f(x)dx &=& \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}f(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{a-y-t}f(x)dx}{t}\\
&=& \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int_{a-y-t}^{a-y}f(x)dx}{t} \quad \textbf{mean value theorem for integration}\\
&=& \lim_{t\to0}f(\theta_t)\quad \textbf{where}\quad \theta_t\in(a-y-t,a-y)\\
&=& f(a-y)\end{eqnarray*}$$